# Pure Js onclick element doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble when i run this code under greasemonkey the last position working and run function.

```
var arry = [];
arry = GM_listValues();
for ( var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {  
    document.getElementById('moje_menu').innerHTML = document.getElementById('moje_menu').innerHTML + '<p id="' + arry[i] + '">' + arry[i] + '</p>';
    document.getElementById(arry[i]).onclick = delete;
}
```

On 10 position the last working ... WHY ????

Comment: shouldn't you use += instead of =

Comment: @krisph it will not matter - a=a+b is the same as a+=b. When you replace innerHTML, your event handlers are all removed. That is the reason for this issue

Comment: Was just saying, uses less space and less space is always better =]   there is no debugging to give an actual answer. =/

Answer (score 2):

When you replace the innerHTML you remove all previous event handlers.

**In plain JS you can detect the click in the div but you need to check the event**:

```js
function removeP(p) {
  console.log(p.id);
}  
var arry = ["a","b","c"];
window.onload=function() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {  
    document.getElementById('moje_menu').innerHTML += '<p id="' + arry[i] + '">' + arry[i] + '</p>';
  }
  document.getElementById('moje_menu').onclick=function(e) {
    var event = e?e:window.event,tgt = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (tgt.tagName.toLowerCase()=="p") {
      console.log(tgt.id);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="moje_menu"></div>
```

**Alternative is inline since you generate the P anyway**

```
var arry = [];
arry = GM_listValues();
for ( var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {  
    document.getElementById('moje_menu').innerHTML += '<p id="' + arry[i] + '" onclick="delete(this)">' + arry[i] + '</p>';
}
```

You can the modify delete (poor name for a function since delete is a built-in method) to handle the passed paragraph

**Example:**

```js
function removeP(p) {
  console.log(p.id);
}  
var arry = ["a","b","c"];
for ( var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {  
  document.getElementById('moje_menu').innerHTML += '<p id="' + arry[i] + '" onclick="removeP(this)">' + arry[i] + '</p>';
}
```

```html
<div id="moje_menu"></div>
```

**In jQuery you can easily delegate:**

```js
function removeP() {
  console.log(this.id);
}  
$(function() {
  
  var arry = ["a","b","c"];
  var $menu = $('#moje_menu');
  for (var i=0; i<arry.length; i++) {  
    $menu.append($('<p/>',{"id":arry[i], "text":arry[i]}))
  }
  $menu.on("click","p",removeP);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moje_menu"></div>
```

Comment: I need pure JS not Jquery

Comment: so take the FIRST example!

Comment: I have updated my examples with one that detects the click on the div instead

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution i dont like them but works.

```
var arry = [];
arry = GM_listValues();

for ( var i = 0; i<arry.length; i++) { 

 // if(arry[i].search('player')==''){
    document.getElementById('moje_menu').innerHTML += '<p class="lista_farm" id="'+arry[i]+'">'+arry[i]+'</p>';
    //document.getElementById(arry[i]).onclick = usun_farme;
//}
}
var lista_farm = document.getElementsByClassName('lista_farm');

for(var i = 0; i<lista_farm.length; i++){
  lista_farm[i].onclick = usun_farme;
}
```